# Golang type assertion issue

Tags: go

I am trying to call this Gorp function http://godoc.org/github.com/coopernurse/gorp#DbMap.Get

I am doing this:

```
       // ClassType
    obj, err := c.Gorp.Get(entities.ClassType{}, class.ClassTypeCode)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    class.ClassType = obj.(*entities.ClassType)  <<<<<<<<< Error here
```

My Class looks like this:

```
package entities

import (
    "time"
)

type Class struct {
    Id                int
    ClassTypeCode     string
    VideoPath         string
    VideoSize         int
    Duration          float64
    CreatedAt         time.Time
    VisibleAt         time.Time
    NoLongerVisibleAt time.Time

    // Relationships
    ClassType  ClassType
    Instructor User
    Equipment  []Equipment
}
```

I keep getting this error message: 
interface conversion: interface is *entities.ClassType, not entities.ClassType

If I change my code to :

```
            // ClassType
    obj, err := c.Gorp.Get(entities.ClassType{}, class.ClassTypeCode)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    class.ClassType = obj.(*entities.ClassType)
```

I then get this message:

```
cannot use obj.(*entities.ClassType) (type *entities.ClassType) as type entities.ClassType in assignment
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Updated, was a copy and paste-o.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class.ClassType = *obj.(*entities.ClassType)
```

Comment: Thank you!! I have spent hours stuck on these damn pointers. What is up here, why does the type assertion need a pointer?

Comment: It doesn't, it needs to dereference to get the value rather than the memory address.